# Is this disrespectfully terse answer delete-worthy in LQP?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I was reviewing Low Quality Posts and I've received the following answer (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080251/spring-data-elasticsearch-scan-and-scroll-paged-result-is-not-working/44380920#44380920)):
[image]

1. I don't want to judge on technical inaccuracies as it's not the topic of LQP,
2. I wouldn't feel respected with such answer by my teammate and I always expect answers on Stack Overflow to act as talking face to face in a team, but this is personal feeling.

How do you think, is this low quality or not? Would you also skip or would you judge? I'm asking to improve my skills on reviewing.

Note: I don't find this question a duplicate, as I'm not having problems with clicking "skip". I'm asking what the correct judgement is. There is no better place to learn from those that are more experienced in reviewing then meta yet. Maybe this should be a feature-request for reviewing tutors?

Comment: When in doubt, skip

Comment: I skipped, but I'm trying to be better and better also in reviewing, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: That's why I didn't post it as an answer! ;)

Comment: I sometimes find looking at the question helps to determine if the question is low quality or not. Can you post a link to the question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's do a test. Do you have doubts now:

> I faced the same problem, page must be not null, and `hasNext()` is always true.
>   `hasContent()` can assert the page. Replace `hasNext()` with `hasContent()`, and try again....

Although the answer is not very elaborate in content, it is struggling with style and (English) grammar. The editor of that answer made it actually worse by seemingly randomly adding backticks to set code apart.

That answer is not low quality, it should be edited into shape, I think `hasContent()` might be the solution and for that reason it should not be deleted by the reviewers in the LQP queue.

Comment: Its quite strange that this formatting was added by an editor and approved by two reviewers, who obviously don't pay much attention.

Comment: It's all for the badges @Tom it is all for the badges :( ...

Comment: Is there a "be a review-robot" badge? :D These badges are quite easy to get, even when paying attention, but yeah, it is easier to just click "approve" :(.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what the first part of that answer is trying to convey.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Neither can I and I suspect that's why none of the reviewers attempted to improve the edit. You can't edit something to make it make sense when you can't tell what it's trying to say in the first place.